# Export a function from another js file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple question.

Also, how can I export a function from another js file? Doesn't the following work?

```
import B from './B'
function A(){
   const a = B.test()
}
```

```
export default function B(){
  async function test(){
  ...
  return a;
  }
}
```

I don't know how I can fix that, can someone explain my mistake?

Comment: You need to return `test` function from `B` function and to call `test` function, you first need to call `B` function and then call the `test` function: `B()()`.

Comment: In function A I wanna call more than one function from function B.

Comment: Can you please show me the logic in the test function

Comment: @CrispenGari ```  async function retrieveYears() {
    const Years = Parse.Object.extend("Years");
    const query = new Parse.Query(Years);
    const ylist = [];
    await query.find().then(function (results) {
      results.forEach((element, index) => {
        ylist[index] = element.get("Title");
      });
    });
    return ylist.sort();
  }```

Comment: I've just posted an alternative answer, look for it and Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Do you need wrapper function? I would just do it like this:

```
export const test = async () => { 
   /** other code  **/
   return a;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because I can export only at the top level. But I will call a function from the function B.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because you're exporting a function rather than an object containing functions which is what you need to do here.

Change your export to:

```
const B = {
  async test() {
    ...
    return a;
  },
  // any other function declarations here
};

export default B;
```

You can import the same way as you're doing already.

You can actually shorten the export code to:

```
export default {
  async test() {
    ...
    return a
  },
};
```

However the first approach would allow you to access functions from the exported functions, from within the exported functions and is probably a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
export default function B(){
  async function test(){
  ...
  return a;
  }
}
```

To

```
const B = {
  async function test(){
  ...
  return a;
  }
}  

export default B
```

Don't change A, and try again